# Use readLines in successive chunks R

Tags: r

I've got a file with 2m+ lines.

To avoid memory overload, I want to read these lines in chunks and then perform further processing with the lines in the chunk.

I read that `readLines` is the fastest but I could not find a way to read chunks with `readlines`.

```
raw = readLines(target_file, n = 500)
```

But what I'd want is to then have a `readLines` for `n = 501:1000`, e.g.

```
raw = readLines(target_file, n = 501:1000)
```

Is there a way to do this in R?

Comment: Look into connections. See `?file`. Basically, set up a connection to that file and read X many lines in each iteration. The mechanics underlying this will keep track of where you are for the next read, so R won't have to start from the top of the file. Another super fast reading package that may be worth looking into is `iotools`, which works with connections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this helps someone in the future:

The `readr` package has just what I was looking for: a function to read lines in chunks.

[`read_lines_chunked`](https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/read_lines_chunked.html) reads a file in chunks of lines and then expects a callback to be run on these chunks.

Let `f` be the function needed for storing a chunk for later use:

```
f = function(x, pos){
 filename = paste("./chunks/chunk_", pos, ".RData", sep="")
 save(x, file = filename)
}
```

Then I can use this in the main wrapper as:

```
read_lines_chunked(file = target_json
               , chunk_size = 10000
               , callback = SideEffectChunkCallback$new(f)
               )
```

Works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how many variables (columns) you have, but `data.table::fread` is a very fast alternative to what you want:

```
require(data.table)

raw <- fread(target_file)
```

Comment: fread won't work because the target file contains a json object per line - and fread does not seem to handle this well.

Comment: what does the data look like?